# Magento: Dupliacte terms in shipping method names

Tags: php, magento

When I call `$order->getShippingDescription()`, the returned string contains duplicated words of the carrier for orders paid with Paypal and Google Checkout. An example of the returned string is..

```
USPS - USPS - Priority
```

or

```
UPS - UPS Ground
```

Does anybody why the terms appear twice only for orders paid with Paypal and Google Checkout?

*** Update: found a related thread. http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/76265/#t213276

Comment: I'm guessing because of the way Magento converts data when passing along info to their APIs. I believe you're looking at two bits of info, USPS as the carrier, USPS Priority as the carrier shipping method.

Answer (score 0):

try to look for opposite and see where in the code those methods make

```
setShippingDescription();
```

usually it is title, name , label or something similar